# content_tag inside another content_tag in rail

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a way to have one content_tag inside another. 
I have this right now.

```
content_tag :span, "", :class => "container"
```

Which outputs

```
<span class="container"></span>
```

I want to be able to have

```
<span class="container"><span class="icon"></span></span>
```

or

```
<div class="container"><span class="icon"></span></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
content_tag :div, :class => "container" do
  content_tag :span, :class => "icon" do
    "Some More Content"
  end
end
```